Flutter getting the keyboard height before it render
i am creating chat app using flutter framework and i am trying to add emoji keyboard
the problem is that I can't switch between the main keyboard and emoji keyboard smoothly
is there any suggestions or references that could help me?
i have tried to set resizing in scaffold to false and use media querie but nothing helpful

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Android doesn't work that way.  The keyboard app itself decides it's height.  The keyboard app can be changed by either the OEM or the user.  The OS, when it decides it needs to show the keyboard, will start the InputMethodService of the default keyboard app and will ask it how big it is.  There's no hook to ask for that data by the app before the keyboard is displayed.
In fact there's no promise that the keyboard will even be at the bottom of the screen.  I've written floating keyboards before that appear elsewhere-  the keyboard app just needs to set the appropriate insets when asked for them.  Appearing at the bottom is just the default implementation.

So how does WhatsApp and telegram handle that smooth toggle between soft keyboard and emoji keyboard?

I may have found a solution for you. Please check the link below:
switch_emoji_picker_keyboard_flutter_tutorial
